WebAssembly exported function: Cannot read properties of undefined
I'm trying to run lightningcss on a WebWorker module for my JavaScript application.
I imported it as a module as follows:
import * as lightningcss from './index.mjs';

and tried using the function as below:
let code = lightningcss.transform({
    code: bufferedTextInput,
    minify: true,
    sourceMap: false
});

However, on running the script in my browser, I encountered the following error:
index.mjs:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transform')
    at Module.transform (index.mjs:41:15)
    at wasm-worker.js:9:29

I tried troubleshooting on the web but to no avail. How would I go about fixing this problem?

lightningcss  is undefined, look at at Module.transform (index.mjs:41:15). I think you should include that line into the question

The parser should be executed not in the browser but in the node environment.Which means that it should first parse the css and only then send it to the browser. I advise you to understand the principles of how bundlers and parsers work, and how JavaScript works in different environments.
nodejs/browser, npm and about runtime and development environment
Link to documentation
Use it with parcel as shown in the documentation.
import { transform } from 'lightningcss';

let { code, map } = transform({
  filename: 'style.css',
  code: Buffer.from('.foo { color: red }'),
  minify: true,
  sourceMap: true
});

don't forget to install it first
npm install --save-dev lightningcss


Is there any way we can use tools like browserify to bundle it all up? Since it's rust compiled to wasm I am assuming it can also work inside the browser?
